# img inside hidden div pixelated for a short time when shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I suppose this had been answered before, but I couldn't find a similar issue on the web.

I have an img element inside a hidden div (a side menu). It is not hidden actually, it is an absolutely positioned div residing outside of the body borders. When user clicks a button to open the menu, I make use of jQuery's animate to move it back into the viewport by playing with its left property. The setup is as follows:

```
.menu { 
    .
    .
    .
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -200px;
}
```

When user clicks the button to open the menu, I run this animation:

```
$('.menu').animate({
        left: "+=200"
    },
    500,
    function() {
        // stuff here
    }
);
```

The problem is, when this animation is completed, the img inside the menu is pixelated for a short period of time, like 3 seconds, then it renders correctly. This happens everytime I close and open the menu again. How can I solve this?

EDIT

I've prepared a fiddle, but couldn't reproduce the issue in the fiddle. Image renders with no problem in the fiddle. I am posting the link here anyway, maybe that could help to understand the setup. Could the reason be other elements present in the document at the time of the animation? Or could it be about hte size of the image?

http://jsfiddle.net/j5aecuqx/

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in a `jsFiddle` so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I've updated the question with a fiddle

Comment: This sounds like a browser rendering delay. Could be affected by number of elements on page, image type/compression, etc. Shame we can't see a reprodiction of the issue...

Comment: @Fly What I don't understand here is, this happens even when the image is already loaded, when I hide and show the div again, the image is not fetched from the network as it is already fetched, but still it is shown pixelated

Comment: Right. By rendering, I mean the browser's drawing of the element onto the canvas. I've seen this sort of effect with text in Bootstrap tooltips in Firefox. Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Yes, the issue seems to be happening on Chrome and IE (10), not on Firefox in this case, image is rendered correctly there.